# Angular2 sibling element selector

Tags: javascript, dom, typescript, angular

I wanted to hide all the previous elements, which is before `.map-page` element.

I'm loading ionic app and I need to hide previous pages if `.map-page` is detected on the dom.

[image]

in jQuery this is so simple `$('.map-page').siblings().hide()`, but in angular 2.. I'm not sure which functions to use to do that.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Since you're traversing the dom, in angular, it is suggested that you use a directive.  Inside your directive, you have access to $element

EX:

```
app.directive('hide-siblings', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $element.siblings().hide()
        },
    }
});
```

EDIT:  That is only if you have jquery and also probably not the best way.  It may be better to add this directive to all your elements and use:

```
app.directive('hide-siblings', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            if(!$element.hasClass('map-page'))
                $element.hide()

        },
    }
});
```

Comment: He is stating that he is using angular 2 but your solution is with angular 1.